# Why is my send grid module not compiling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

0

I'm trying to use the SendGrid module in my React application to send an email using a contact form. However, when I run npm start, I encounter the following error:

```
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '.../node_modules/@sendgrid/helpers/classes'
The error message suggests that the 'fs' and 'path' modules cannot be resolved in the @sendgrid/helpers/classes/attachment.js file.
```

I also receive the warning:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

Here is my project structure for indexfirebase.js:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var express_1 = require("express");
var mail_1 = require("@sendgrid/mail");
var path_browserify_1 = require("path-browserify");
// Set up SendGrid API key
mail_1.default.setApiKey("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");
// Create Express app
var app = (0, express_1.default)();
// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express_1.default.json());
// Route to handle sending emails
app.post("/send-email", function (req, res) {
    var _a = req.body, Name = _a.Name, Email = _a.Email, Message = _a.Message, submitbutton = _a.submitbutton;
    var msg = {
        to: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
        from: "gdscusyd@gmail.com",
        subject: "Example Subject",
        text: "Name: ".concat(Name, "\nEmail: ").concat(Email, "\nMessage: ").concat(Message, "\nSubmit Button: ").concat(submitbutton),
        html: "<p>Name: ".concat(Name, "</p><p>Email: ").concat(Email, "</p><p>Message: ").concat(Message, "</p><p>Submit Button: ").concat(submitbutton, "</p>"),
    };
    mail_1.default
        .send(msg)
        .then(function () {
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error.toString());
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send email" });
    });
});
// Set up fallback for path module
path_browserify_1.resolve.fallback = { path: path_browserify_1.require.resolve("path-browserify") };
// Start the server
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

I believe this error is occurring because the fs and path modules are part of the Node.js environment and are not available in a browser environment.

My questions are:

1. Can I use the SendGrid module in a browser-based React application?
2. Is it possible to fix this error and make the SendGrid module work in my React application?
3. If it's not possible, what alternatives can I use to send emails from a contact form in a React application?
   I appreciate any help or guidance to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!